# Understanding difference equation

Tags: functional-equations, finite-differences

I was given an example

$$R_n = R_{n-1} + R_{n-2} $$

This equation is given as an second-order equation.

Why is it so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that it is second-order refers to the fact that the largest difference in indices is $2$.  For example,

$$
R_{n+4}=3R_{n+1}^2+R_n
$$

is a fourth-order difference equation and

$$
R_{n+3}=2R_{n+2}\cdot R_{n+1}
$$

is a second order difference equation.

If you're familiar with ODEs, the terminology is analogous.

Comment: $$R_n = R_{n-1} + R_{n-2} $$  The difference is because of $$R_n and R_{n-2} $$ which determine the equation to be second-order?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: The techniques for solving second order difference equations are analogous to those used in solving second order differential equations (complementary function, 'particular integral'..)

Comment: @liangteh:   the reason for interest in the order is that it tells you how many old terms can influence a new one.  For a second order equation you need two initial conditions.  For the first of GleasSpty's examples you would need 4.

Answer (score 1):

One explanation is that one solves (see [Recurrence relation, Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), under "Solving") the following homogeneous difference equation (or recurrence relation) with constant coefficients

$$a_{n}+Aa_{n-1}+Ba_{n-2}=0,$$

by means of the **second degree** characteristic equation

$$r^2+Ar+B=0,$$

pretty much as one woud solve a homogeneous second-order linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients.